# Lambda SAM deploy giving error 'EC2DescribePolicy' at 'policyArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 20

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm using AWS SAM to deploy a Lambda using cloudformation. The lambda uses the StartInstancesCommand,StopInstancesCommand and DescribeInstancesCommand api to turn instances on and off on schedule.

Using both the `EC2DescribePolicy` or `EC2FullAccessPolicy` SAM policy templates, I have been encountering the following error on:

`sam deploy`

> 1 validation error detected: Value
> 'EC2DescribePolicy' at 'policyArn'
> failed to satisfy constraint:
> Member must have length greater
> than or equal to 20 (Service:
> AmazonIdentityManagement;
> Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError;

[image: Screenshot of SAM deploy error 'policyArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 20]

How can I fix this error? Do I have to specify 'policyArn' manually?

My template.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  test-function

Resources:
  TestFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: test-function/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 60
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
        - EC2DescribePolicy
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        ScheduledEvent:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: cron(0 8 * * ? *)
            Enabled: True
```

Version information:

```
$ sam --version
SAM CLI, version 1.60.0
$ node --version
v16.17.0
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-templates.html) states:

> For every policy template you specify in your AWS SAM template file, you must always specify an object containing the policy template's placeholder values. If a policy template does not require any placeholder values, you must specify an empty object.

So you should have:

```
Policies:
  - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
  - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
  - EC2DescribePolicy : {}
```

Comment: Thanks, the deploy works with the line you recommended. What about `EC2FullAccessPolicy`? `EC2FullAccessPolicy` requires a string, is an empty string ok?

Comment: @glcheetham yes you need to do this for every SAM policy template

Comment: unfortunately using as written with `EC2FullAccessPolicy` gives `Incorrect type. Expected "string".`

Comment: @glcheetham looks like EC2FullAccessPolicy isn't a SAM policy template

Comment: yes you're right, there isn't a SAM policy template called EC2FullAccessPolicy. How can I give the lambda `ec2:Start*` and `ec2:Stop` permissions?

Comment: @glcheetham you have two options. either you use an AWS managed policy or you create your own policy